# Make MIDI messages and audio signal transit in the same jack cable

Tags: audio, filter, serial, midi

I know it's a crazy (bad) idea, but still: I hate having many cables attached to a music instrument when I move in the room. Let's take the example of a Akai MPC500 sampler: it is battery powered (so no power cable needed), but I still have 2 cables attached to it:

- a long 6.35 mono jack cable (unbalanced, it's ok for this purpose)
- a MIDI cable (DIN connector on both ends)

**Question: could we make both a audio channel (20Hz-20kHz signal) and MIDI signal (serial data @31250 baud) transit in the same jack cable (i.e. only 2 wires: ground and signal)?**

Probably with a filter, like when with ADSL 20 years ago, we could use Internet and someone talking on the phone (not VOIP but old analog phone) at the same time.

Something like that:

[image]

Comment: If you're building custom adapters/ends anyway, is there a reason you don't want to use a 3-conductor cable?

Comment: @KevinReid I have lots of (good) mono jack cables to use, I'd like to avoid buying ones. And also because I'm curious about this challenge: make both bytes data and audio data transit in the same wires :)

Comment: Sure, modulate your signal on a high frequency carrier and you should be able to do this. I have strong doubts as to whether it's worth the trouble, though.

Comment: do a ultra-sonic Frequency Shift Keying of the MIDI, well above the audio; and keep the MIDI channel amplitude well below the audio level, to ensure minimal residual MIDI after high-pass-filtering

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Can we do this with only a few small components, so that it would fit in each Y cable/adapter on both ends ? What would be these components?

Comment: @downvoter: please leave a comment about how could I improve the question, thanks in advance

Comment: @Basj (I did not downvote but) combining and splitting audio with MIDI over two wires with only a few small components not possible.

Comment: the NE567 is a tone decoder. Other NE56X parts may do the encoding. You will need about a square inch of board area.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf do you think it will require a power supply or could it be midi powered? (I recently made a MIDI message processor based on ATtiny or ATmega fully powered by MIDI - no battery or external supply needed)

Comment: Would someone have a sample schematic that does more or less a similar thing? I will try to adapt it to MIDI

Comment: @analogsystemsrf a square inch would be OK. If you have an example schematic, feel free to post even a short answer.

Comment: ohhhh you could use a NE555 to produce the two tones, at some frequencies far above audio, so the tones are easy to filter out. And make them WEAK (10 milliVolts should be fine for the NE567 to detect).

Comment: @analogsystemsrf for example one tone at 50 Khz for MIDI serial bit 0, and one tone at 100 Khz for MIDI serial bit 1? Something like that? How do you filter this at the end on the receiver end? Thanks again for your ideas!

Comment: read the NE555 datasheet;

Comment: I think at this point you might as well have a microcontroller that samples audio and MIDI signals and digitize them to transmit through the wire. Or reads the MIDI signals and transmit them FSK with a very high carrier frequency.

Comment: @hatsunearu That would also require a 24-bit DAC (to have good audio quality), and 24-bit ADC on the other end (often only available as very small SMD), volume control to avoid saturation, etc. so at the end it would be like building a small soundcard... so I think this would be a little bit overkill here. I'll read more about Frequency Shift Keying to see if it would work here! Feel free to post an answer about this if you have an idea about how to do it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: How much audio quality do you want on the other end? Any scheme other than the one I said with the full digitization will cause some degredation in audio quality (maybe unperceptable, but still)

Comment: @hatsunearu I would like to keep the full audio quality with no digitization on the range 20hz-20khz. (Having noise at 50khz or 100 khz is no problem)

Comment: OK then the FSK thing is probably your best bet. But beware even the best modems will still leak some energy into the lower frequencies unless you're ultra careful about system level design. I don't want to disparage your abilities but I highly doubt you're going to get a good board that meets even 16 bit noise floor.